# Open file in Midnight Commander directly from console?

Tags: bash, vi, mc, mcedit

I mean without launching MC.
Like "vi somefile", but in MC editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mcedit is the 'standalone' internal editor of midnight commander

Answer (score 1):

Check `man mc`:

```
  -e [file], --edit[=file]
          Start the internal editor.  If the file is specified, open it on
          startup.  See also mcedit (1).
```